# image scan solo funciona con usuario root y los demas?

Tags: linux

Tengo un inconveniente con una impresora multifuncional Epson L380. Tengo Opensuse leap 42.2 instale el aplicativo image scan, lo probe y me funcione el escaner pero en usuario root. Cuando cambio de usuario y hago el scaneo no me guarda lo que scanee. Hay alguna solucion para esto?

Comment: La única solución fue instalar xsane y me funciono a la perfección.

Comment: Usando el comando simple-scan desde consola me funcionaba, pero haciéndolo desde el icono en el buscador de aplicaciones enviaba un mensaje de error "no se puede enviar el comando al scanner ..." Lo solucione cómo dijeron arriba *usermod -a -G scanner usuario*

Answer (score 4):

Eso es porque tu usuario no tiene permisos. Comprueba a los grupos que pertenece el usuario. Lo más común es que para poder escanear tenga que pertenecer al grupo *scanner*. Puedes añadir tu usuario al grupo *scanner* con el siguiente comando

```
usermod -a -G scanner usuario
```

Para que se apliquen los nuevos permisos tienes que volver a iniciar la sesión con tu usuario. Puedes comprobar los grupos de tu usuario con el comando *groups*.

Comment: Es que no hay grupo scanner, cuando escaneo el aplicativo me dice doonde guardo el archivo.